# PHPExcel - Proceed if sheet name equals

Tags: php, phpexcel

Here's the scenario, I want to be able to run a specific section of PHP code for each different excel sheet, so basically if I have a workbook that has the following sheets, "Funds", "Accounts", "Spending Data", how can I look through each sheet to be able to run separate code depending on the sheet name, so for example, I only want to fetch the cell data from A5:D5 on "Funds", but on "Accounts" I want to get the A5:P5, etc.

I've tried using the `foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)`, but that just loops through each sheet, which I would expect it to do then runs the same code on each sheet which is not what I'm looking for.

Sorry if I've not explained it very well, but if there was someway I could do something like;

```
if sheetname == "Funds" {
     //get cells A5:D5
}
if sheetname == "Accounts" {
    //get cells A5:P5
}
```

etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards.

Comment: And what is the exact problem? You can't get name of a sheet or what?

Comment: I think the problem is at the moment that the code is running for every sheet on the workbook, where I only want it to run for certain sheets, as per my example above.

Comment: I think that this link can be useful :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081669/read-only-specific-sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getTitle` to know the sheet's title:

```
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
{
  $sheetname = $worksheet->getTitle();
  if ($sheetname == "Funds") 
  {
    //get cells A5:D5
  }

 if ($sheetname == "Accounts")
 {
   //get cells A5:P5
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you AnatPort, but how do I use this solution you provided to select only stated sheet, such as "Funds"?

Comment: you can combine this with the `getWorksheetIterator` you've mentioned in your question. edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: That doesn't really help me, as it's not just one sheet I need to be able to read, it can be up to 12 sheets, each with a different cell range...

Comment: this loops through all of your work sheets, you just add more `if` statements to change the behavior depends on the sheet name. it does not apply only to one worksheet.  maybe I misunderstood what your are trying to accomplish...

Comment: Thank you AnatPort, your amended answer above worked, with a small adjustment to add $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName('Funds);, so it looks like this now:

`foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
{
  $sheetname = $worksheet->getTitle();
  if ($sheetname == "Funds") 
  {
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndexByName('Funds');
    //get cells A5:D5
  }
}`